# How to get the second point in a line segment knowing its first point, distance and perpendicular line segment?

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, algorithms

I need to get the second point in a line segment knowing its first point, distance and perpendicular line segment. The line segments need to intersect , thus the direction of the incomplete line segment could differ based on the location of its first point. The problem I have now is that I don't know how to obtain the direction of the incomplete line segment.

This is what is known:

`a1 = (30, 30)`

`a2 = (10, 30)`

`b1 = (30, 35)`

`d = 30` (distance of line segment b)

[image]

I tried the following:

Get perpendicular slope a.

```
m = (b2.x - b1.x) / (b2.y - b1.y);
```

Get horizontal direction.

```
hd = ?  // either 1 or -1
```

Get a2.

```
a2.x = a1.x + d * cos(atan(m)) * hd;
a2.y = a1.y + d * sin(atan(m));
```

I am missing the step to get the horizontal direction of the slope of `b`, I was unable to recognize the pattern. Or perhaps there is a better and shorter algorithm to figure out point `b2`?

Comment: There are two possibilities for $B_2$. The drawing suggests that you’re to choose the one for which $\overrightarrow{B_1B_2}$ is rotated counterclockwise from $\overrightarrow{A_1A_2}$. Is that the case?

Comment: @amd the drawing represents the wanted outcome. I will edit the question to make clear that the line segments need to intersect.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

You could write

- $$\vec{A_1A_2}•\vec{B_1B_2}=0$$
- $$||\vec{B_1B_2}||^2=900$$

and solve the system.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $A_1A_2$ is a segment parallel to X-Axis. And also that $B_1$ is a point directly above $A_1$. So, the diagram looks like this :[image]
It's trivial to figure out the coordinates of $B_2$ now.